# Vuetify v-text-field Default Slot Not Working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to use a custom filter with the Vuetify v-text-field control. I am having trouble getting a value to show using the default slot of the v-text-field control. It is apparently derived from v-input, which seems to work fine.

This does not work:

```
<v-text-field>
   {{ purchasePrice | currency }}
</v-text-field>
```

This works:

```
<v-input>
   {{ purchasePrice | currency }}
</v-input>
```

Am I missing a template slot or something? I've been able to successfully use the "append" and "prepend" slots on this control, but not the "default" slot. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this as well, and did some source diving. Documenting my findings below:

As of Vuetify `2.5.8` (most recent version), and any other `2+` version, `default` slot is ignored on `v-text-element`.

The relevant part in the [source code of VTextField.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/32dcb0640556b7424a1d7af462f32c20d4e49749/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.ts#L334):

```
genDefaultSlot () {
  return [
    this.genFieldset(),
    this.genTextFieldSlot(),
    this.genClearIcon(),
    this.genIconSlot(),
    this.genProgress(),
  ]
},
```

it overrides `genDefaultSlot` [method of VInput.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/32dcb0640556b7424a1d7af462f32c20d4e49749/packages/vuetify/src/components/VInput/VInput.ts#L163), which is included as a mixin in VTextField.ts:

```
genDefaultSlot () {
  return [
    this.genLabel(),
    this.$slots.default,
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I could only make it work with named slots: (Also, I'm reusing this component, so it accepts another slot on the inside)

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-text-field
      :type="type"
      v-bind="
        // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance
        $attrs
      "
      @input="$emit('update', $event)"
      v-on="
        // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components
        $listeners
      "
    >
    <!-- ⬇️ HERE  ⬇️ -->
      <template v-slot:label>
        <slot></slot>
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
  </v-layout>
</template>


<script>
import { defaultMaterialTextFiledsProps } from '~/config/inputsStyle'

// See https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/master/src/components/_base-input-text.vue
export default {
  // Disable automatic attribute inheritance, so that $attrs are
  // passed to the <input>, even if it's not the root element.
  // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text',
      // Only allow types that essentially just render text boxes.
      validator(value) {
        return [
          'email',
          'number',
          'password',
          'search',
          'tel',
          'text',
          'url'
        ].includes(value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```